# Why did JBoss start before it was deployed?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

My application architecture is: ear->war (based on Maven).
The IDE I use is IntelliJ IDEA.
I used the exploded mode to deploy.
My JBoss version is 4.2.
Why did JBoss start before it was deployed?

The log of JBoss startup is as follows：

```
16:07:06,838 INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)] Started in 5s:842ms
Connected to server
[2019-02-01 04:07:06,856] Artifact application-jiangsu:ear exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
16:07:06,867 INFO  [EARDeployer] Init J2EE application: file:/Users/zhanshifeng/Documents/ccssoftDocument/workSpace/js-zhdd-idea/application-jiangsu/target/application-jiangsu-1.0.77-SNAPSHOT.ear/
16:07:07,147 INFO  [EARDeployer] Started J2EE application: file:/Users/zhanshifeng/Documents/ccssoftDocument/workSpace/js-zhdd-idea/application-jiangsu/target/application-jiangsu-1.0.77-SNAPSHOT.ear/
[2019-02-01 04:07:07,155] Artifact application-jiangsu:ear exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2019-02-01 04:07:07,155] Artifact application-jiangsu:ear exploded: Deploy took 299 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

JBoss deployment requires communication with the server via JXM so that IDE can instruct it where the web app is located and ask it to load it from that location. Obviously, it's not possible when the server is stopped.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, but the root of the problem is that jboss has been started, but the application has not been deployed yet.

Comment: According to the log you've provided, the app was successfully deployed. Contact support via https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new if you need further assistance.

Comment: 16:07:06,838 INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)] Started in 5s:842ms         
  Then printed the following：    [2019-02-01 04:07:06,856] Artifact application-jiangsu:ear exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

Comment: JBoss reports it was deployed: `Artifact application-jiangsu:ear exploded: Deploy took 299 milliseconds`. What makes you think otherwise?